# Java named backreferences not matching

Tags: java, sql, regex, parsing, backreference

I'm writing a simplified SQL parser that's using regexes to match each valid command. I'm stuck on matching the following:

attribute1 type1, attribute2 type2, attribute3 type3, ...

Where attributes are names of table columns, and types can be a CHAR(size), INT, or DEC. This is used in a CREATE TABLE statement:

`CREATE TABLE student (id INT, name CHAR(20), gpa DEC);`

To debug it, I'm trying to match this:

`id INT, name CHAR(20), gpa DEC`

with this:

`(?<attributepair>[A-Za-z0-9_]+ (INT|(CHAR\([0-9]{1,3}\))|DEC))(, \k<attributepair>)*`

I even tried it without naming the backreference:

`([A-Za-z0-9_]+ (INT|(CHAR\([0-9]{1,3}\))|DEC))(, \1)*`

I tested the latter regex expression with regexpal and it matched, but both don't when I try it in my Java program. Is there something I'm missing? How can I make this work? Perhaps this has something to do with how I'm calling Pattern.compile(), like if I'm missing a flag or not. I'm also have JDK v7.

**Update:** I've found that although matches() returns false, lookingAt() and find() return true. It's matching each individual attribute. I want to craft my regex so it matches the whole expression rather than each attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *"match as many time as possible and join all the groups together"* in **Java**.
You either have to do it yourself using:

```
while(matcher.find()) {
    // ...
}
```

... or using a regex that already matches everything in a single call to `find`.

---

For example, you could try the following regex (as Java **String**) instead, which will match all your attributes at once.

```
(?:\\w+ (?:INT|CHAR(?:\\(\\d{1,3}\\))?|DEC)(?:, )?)+
```

Here is a working example:

```
final String str = "CREATE TABLE student (id INT, name CHAR(20), gpa DEC);";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\w+ (?:INT|CHAR(?:\\(\\d{1,3}\\))?|DEC)(?:, )?)+");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());  // prints "id INT, name CHAR(20), gpa DEC"
};
```

Output:

```
id INT, name CHAR(20), gpa DEC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like `([A-Za-z0-9_]+ (INT|(CHAR\([0-9]{1,3}\))|DEC))(, \1)*` the backreference is for what the first group actually matched.

Ie, `id INT, id INT, name CHAR(20), gpa DEC` would work with the backreference in the sense that `id INT, id INT` would become part of the same match. (If you stick that in regexpal you'll see the difference quite clearly based on the highlights.)